# validate webhook using java Event.validateReceivedEvent always fails signature validation

Tags: java, paypal, paypal-webhooks

I prepared a servlet in my web site to be notified from PayPal webhook. The development version of the servlet logs the http headers and the body. Here is a screen capture with one example:

[image: Screen capture, collected headers and body]

I've created a "self contained test application" that shows the problem.

```
package com.rsws.renew;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SignatureException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.paypal.api.payments.Event;
import com.paypal.base.Constants;
import com.paypal.base.rest.APIContext;
import com.paypal.base.rest.PayPalRESTException;
import com.paypal.base.rest.PayPalResource;

/**
 * @author Ignacio
 *
 */
public class TestWebHook {

 public static void main(String[] argv) {

    try {
        InputStream is = InvoicePaid.class 
                .getResourceAsStream("/sdk_config.properties"); 
        try { 
            PayPalResource.initConfig(is); 
        } catch (PayPalRESTException e) { 
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

        APIContext apiContext = new APIContext();
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>(PayPalResource.getConfigurations());
        apiContext.setConfigurationMap(map);

        Map<String,String> headers = new HashMap<String,String>();

        // this is the data provided by PayPal sandbox
        map.put(Constants.PAYPAL_WEBHOOK_ID, "3W2725225F637605K");
        String payload = "{\"id\":\"WH-0T490472X6099635W-7LJ29748BW389372K\",\"create_time\":\"2015-09-25T23:14:14Z\",\"resource_type\":\"invoices\",\"event_type\":\"INVOICING.INVOICE.PAID\",\"summary\":\"An invoice was created\",\"resource\":{\"id\":\"INV2-8FSD-3HT6-BRHR-UHYV\",\"number\":\"MM00063\",\"status\":\"PAID\",\"merchant_info\":{\"email\":\"example@outlook.com\",\"first_name\":\"Dennis\",\"last_name\":\"Doctor\",\"business_name\":\"Medical Professional LLC\",\"address\":{\"line1\":\"1234 Main St\",\"line2\":\"Apt 302\",\"city\":\"Portland\",\"state\":\"OR\",\"postal_code\":\"97217\",\"country_code\":\"US\"}},\"billing_info\":[{\"email\":\"example@example.com\",\"business_name\":\"Medical Professionals LLC\",\"language\":\"en_US\"}],\"items\":[{\"name\":\"Sample Item\",\"quantity\":1,\"unit_price\":{\"currency\":\"USD\",\"value\":\"1.00\"},\"unit_of_measure\":\"QUANTITY\"}],\"invoice_date\":\"2015-09-28 PDT\",\"payment_term\":{\"term_type\":\"DUE_ON_RECEIPT\",\"due_date\":\"2015-09-28 PDT\"},\"tax_calculated_after_discount\":true,\"tax_inclusive\":false,\"total_amount\":{\"currency\":\"USD\",\"value\":\"1.00\"},\"payments\":[{\"type\":\"PAYPAL\",\"transaction_id\":\"22592127VV907111U\",\"transaction_type\":\"SALE\",\"method\":\"PAYPAL\",\"date\":\"2015-09-28 14:37:13 PDT\"}],\"metadata\":{\"created_date\":\"2015-09-28 14:35:46 PDT\",\"last_updated_date\":\"2015-09-28 14:37:13 PDT\",\"first_sent_date\":\"2015-09-28 14:35:47 PDT\",\"last_sent_date\":\"2015-09-28 14:35:47 PDT\"},\"paid_amount\":{\"paypal\":{\"currency\":\"USD\",\"value\":\"1.00\"}},\"links\":[{\"rel\":\"self\",\"href\":\"https://api.paypal.com/v1/invoicing/invoices/INV2-8FSD-3HT6-BRHR-UHYV\",\"method\":\"GET\"}]},\"links\":[{\"href\":\"https://api.paypal.com/v1/notifications/webhooks-events/WH-0T490472X6099635W-7LJ29748BW389372K\",\"rel\":\"self\",\"method\":\"GET\"},{\"href\":\"https://api.paypal.com/v1/notifications/webhooks-events/WH-0T490472X6099635W-7LJ29748BW389372K/resend\",\"rel\":\"resend\",\"method\":\"POST\"}]}";
        headers.put("PAYPAL-CERT-URL", "https://api.paypal.com/v1/notifications/certs/CERT-360caa42-fca2a594-df8cd2d5");
        headers.put("PAYPAL-TRANSMISSION-ID", "464163d0-e0ae-11e5-af72-51ae350aaff1");
        headers.put("PAYPAL-TRANSMISSION-TIME", "2016-03-02T19:38:01Z");
        headers.put("PAYPAL-AUTH-ALGO", "SHA256withRSA");
        headers.put("PAYPAL-TRANSMISSION-SIG", "S3AjY87GLp1MP/UsGAWPoEes+laa7xbV4X7pMi9PdC0QR7MoNC/L/O2UThAh1IBzDZ5DGXvkEDvXK9fF0IfoS2QtLJUBm5+UFoo1jJMlH+QCiJUEHSuio2UrFGbxoqaIPcA1PN0tmd5FwikDRPCnpht6pvMvCZV1FEQbBMr9ld3d3XoWBKeWQG+oxAWSTNYJiKQIrM6l/8+hKVQ1LZID8dtR3c7y6eFxNFsDQ3WgwChZZ15vpyhDWQ4t08m3PsWFyjvsQmNRyXQyUeAC8xw96sBwGmHsgwKJwbAamVrWicQqQ/tXuUcqx9Y0pg3P4LuGNPFKzktq9L3ZImTEJxpRLA==");
        // this shows invalid
        System.out.println(Event.validateReceivedEvent(apiContext, headers, payload) ? "valid" : "invalid");

        // this is the data provided in the sdk examples https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Java-SDK/blob/master/rest-api-sdk/src/test/java/com/paypal/base/ValidateCertTest.java
        map.put(Constants.PAYPAL_WEBHOOK_ID, "3RN13029J36659323");
        payload = "{\"id\":\"WH-2W7266712B616591M-36507203HX6402335\",\"create_time\":\"2015-05-12T18:14:14Z\",\"resource_type\":\"sale\",\"event_type\":\"PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED\",\"summary\":\"Payment completed for $ 20.0 USD\",\"resource\":{\"id\":\"7DW85331GX749735N\",\"create_time\":\"2015-05-12T18:13:18Z\",\"update_time\":\"2015-05-12T18:13:36Z\",\"amount\":{\"total\":\"20.00\",\"currency\":\"USD\"},\"payment_mode\":\"INSTANT_TRANSFER\",\"state\":\"completed\",\"protection_eligibility\":\"ELIGIBLE\",\"protection_eligibility_type\":\"ITEM_NOT_RECEIVED_ELIGIBLE,UNAUTHORIZED_PAYMENT_ELIGIBLE\",\"parent_payment\":\"PAY-1A142943SV880364LKVJEFPQ\",\"transaction_fee\":{\"value\":\"0.88\",\"currency\":\"USD\"},\"links\":[{\"href\":\"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/7DW85331GX749735N\",\"rel\":\"self\",\"method\":\"GET\"},{\"href\":\"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/sale/7DW85331GX749735N/refund\",\"rel\":\"refund\",\"method\":\"POST\"},{\"href\":\"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/PAY-1A142943SV880364LKVJEFPQ\",\"rel\":\"parent_payment\",\"method\":\"GET\"}]},\"links\":[{\"href\":\"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/notifications/webhooks-events/WH-2W7266712B616591M-36507203HX6402335\",\"rel\":\"self\",\"method\":\"GET\"},{\"href\":\"https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/notifications/webhooks-events/WH-2W7266712B616591M-36507203HX6402335/resend\",\"rel\":\"resend\",\"method\":\"POST\"}]}";         
        headers.put("PAYPAL-CERT-URL", "https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/notifications/certs/CERT-360caa42-fca2a594-a5cafa77");
        headers.put("PAYPAL-TRANSMISSION-ID", "b2384410-f8d2-11e4-8bf3-77339302725b");
        headers.put("PAYPAL-TRANSMISSION-TIME", "2015-05-12T18:14:14Z");
        headers.put("PAYPAL-AUTH-ALGO", "SHA256withRSA");
        headers.put("PAYPAL-TRANSMISSION-SIG", "vSOIQFIZQHv8G2vpbOpD/4fSC4/MYhdHyv+AmgJyeJQq6q5avWyHIe/zL6qO5hle192HSqKbYveLoFXGJun2od2zXN3Q45VBXwdX3woXYGaNq532flAtiYin+tQ/0pNwRDsVIufCxa3a8HskaXy+YEfXNnwCSL287esD3HgOHmuAs0mYKQdbR4e8Evk8XOOQaZzGeV7GNXXz19gzzvyHbsbHmDz5VoRl9so5OoHqvnc5RtgjZfG8KA9lXh2MTPSbtdTLQb9ikKYnOGM+FasFMxk5stJisgmxaefpO9Q1qm3rCjaJ29aAOyDNr3Q7WkeN3w4bSXtFMwyRBOF28pJg9g==");         
        // this shows valid
        System.out.println(Event.validateReceivedEvent(apiContext, headers, payload) ? "valid" : "invalid");

    } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SignatureException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (PayPalRESTException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

The code shows *valid* when the data has been taken from examples and *invalid* when the data comes from paypal web site.

I wonder why this cannot be validated. Any help is welcome.

Comment: I've added an issue to PayPal-Java-SDK here https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-Java-SDK/issues/157 because the documentation here https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/rest-webhooks-overview/#event-signature is good about how the seed for the signature is calculated and I can go step by step on my app until it is calculated too. (is is this one) 464163d0-e0ae-11e5-af72-51ae350aaff1|2016-03-02T19:38:01Z|3W2725225F637605K|3555709430 but I cannot see the same seed in the information presented in the webhook simulator so I can't really check what's going on

Answer (score 0):

You may want to test the validation with actual sandbox transactions and webhook events. Simulator mock data may not be updated with the sandbox algorithm, and is recommended for testing URL accessibility of your script.